# Angular 2 making one "generic" component out of 2 almost identical components

Tags: angular

I have 2 components that are almost identical and for code reusability I would like to combine those to use in different places in my project. Both are dropdownlists with a checkbox. Only difference is the data that comes in and out.

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, RouteParams, Router, RouterOutlet, RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';
import {FORM_PROVIDERS, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, NgClass, NgIf, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {Component, Inject, Input, OnInit, OnChanges} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, ContentHeaders, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {User} from '/app/interfaces';
import {ActualsComponent } from '../actuals/actual.component';
import {ProjectService} from '../../projects/project.service';
import {LoginService} from '../../login/login.service';
import {SearchPipe} from '../custom-pipes/search-pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'dropdown-users',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/elements/dropdown-users.html',
    providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ProjectService, LoginService],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink, CORE_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet],
    pipes: [SearchPipe]
})

export class DropDownUsers implements OnInit, OnChanges{
    projectdata: Object;
    selectedUsers: Object;

    public showMenu: boolean;
    projectSearchTerm: Control = new Control();
    projectcount: number;

    constructor(@Inject(ProjectService) projectService: ProjectService, @Inject(LoginService) loginService: LoginService, private http: Http,  params: RouteParams) {
        this.showMenu = false;
        loginService.authenticate("user", "pwd");
        this.projectdata = loginService.data;
        this.projectcount = 0;
        this.selectedUsers = new Array();

    }
    addUser(user: User){
        this.selectedUsers.push(user);
    }
}
```

The other component is the same, except it works with users instead of projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a base class with common functionality and extend it when you want to inherit common things, or change/overwrite specific things.

```
class Base {
  selected: any[];
  constructor(DI_ARGS) {
    this.selected = [];
  }
  add(o) { this.selected.push(o); }
}

@Component({ template: `
  <button (click)="add('Mike')">Add User</button>
  <p>selected users: <a *ngFor="#user of selected">{{ user }}, </a></p>
` })
class Users extends Base {
  constructor(DI_ARGS) {
    super(DI_ARGS);
  }
}

@Component({ template: `
  <button (click)="add('build house')">Add Project</button>
  <p>selected projects: <a *ngFor="#project of selected">{{ project }}, </a></p>
` })
class Project extends Base {
  constructor(DI_ARGS) {
    super(DI_ARGS);
  }
}
```

There are some caveats tho':

- You cannot use decorators in base class
- To use dependency injection, you must provide constructor arguments via `super()`
- You can (by default) only extend one class

Comment: Is there a way to commonize the template and css in the base class? I.e., when they are too long for strings.

Comment: @Sasxa I know this is wrong, but if you have time could you help on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44665815/1938988)