# How can I pass a generic type parameter to an Angular2 component?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Let's say I got a component with a fixed input parameter type,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'fixed',
    template: '<div>{{value}}</div>'
})
export class FixedComponent {
    @Input() value: string;
}
```

How do I go about making that parameter type generic, i.e.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'generic',
    template: '<div>{{value}}</div>'
})
export class GenericComponent<T> {
    @Input() value: T;
}
```

That is, how do I pass the type in the template of the parent component?

```
<generic ...></generic>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow but you can use 'any' instead of 'T'.  Optionally you can have another input... @Input('type') type: Type; and then pass the type that way, which you would have to cast your any to that type.

Comment: unknown is an option.  Also within the component itself, the typing doesn't matter because the component itself is generic. The justification for need here is not stated. Remember you can still have a default and base type i.e. CustomComponent<T extends Record<string, BaseWidgetState> = BaseWidgets>

Comment: I believe at the time of the original question, support for default types was not yet a part of Typescript.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that when using [AOT compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) the only way to do this is to replace the generic type with 'any'. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11057

Comment: In this regard, angular seems so half assed. What's the point of typescript and typesafety if some of the fundamental blocks of angular (components and directives) don't support it properly?

Comment: Nothing half-assed here. First you must justify the need, then you can properly state what is half assed. The question doesn't justify the need, it simply asks a syntactical question. At the time this unfortunate comment was made, they had already introduced base types and defaults which is all a generic component should need.

Answer (score 5):

I'm just playing with angular and I made this working by using ViewChild,
by having Inner and Outer Component.

In inner component declaration of component is like:

```
@Injectable() 
@Component({
selector: 'inner-selector',
templateUrl: ...,
styleUrls: ...,
directives: [
...]
export class InnerComponent**<T>**  ...
```

in outer component which called by router I did:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {InnerComponent} from '../components/inner.component';
import {ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector:     'demo-app',
   template:  '<inner-selector></inner-selector>',
directives: [InnerComponent]
})
export class TestPage { 

  @ViewChild(InnerComponent)
  **private innerComponent:InnerComponent<MPSalesHeader>;**
};
```

I don't know is this a good way, but it worked.

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can use generic type parameters in Angular 2 child components.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '<p>Generic Child</p><p>{{cp}}</p>'
})
export class GenericChildComponent<T> {
  @Input() cp: T;
}

import { GenericChildComponent } from './generic-child.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<app-child [cp]="p1"></app-child><hr /><app-child [cp]="p2"></app-child>',
  directives: [GenericChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  p1: string = 'property 1';
  p2: number = 100;
}
```

This works without recourse either to the `ViewChild` technique suggested [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317577/852956) or to a base class technique suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35621915/852956).

Comment: Where you are assigning the generic parameter in the parent component?

Comment: he does it by assigning the child component [cp]="p2"

Comment: However this is NOT a full solution,   Is delays the initialization of T, if it even initializes it properly at all,  How will this work if you child component needs to use T in another generic type that you are getting injected into the constructor

Comment: If anyone want to see another clear example see this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742266/1938988)