# Explicitly specify type for material-dropdown-select instead of dynamic

Tags: angular, dart, angular-material, angular-forms, accessor

## Task

In AngularDart I want to choosing multiple `Foo` objects via `material-dropdown-select` and store selected values in the reactive form.

## My approach

```js
    import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
    import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
    import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';

    @Component(
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '''
        <form [ngFormModel]="form">
          <material-dropdown-select 
            multi 
            ngControl="control1"
            [options]="options"
            [itemRenderer]="renderer"
          >
          </material-dropdown-select>
        </form>
      ''',
      directives: [
        formDirectives,
        MaterialDropdownSelectComponent,
        MultiDropdownSelectValueAccessor,
      ],
      providers: [
        materialProviders,
      ],
    )
    class AppComponent {
      var options = SelectionOptions.fromList([Foo(50, 'op1'), Foo(51, 'op2'), Foo(52, 'op3')]);
      var form;

      AppComponent() {
        form = ControlGroup({
          'control1': Control<List<Foo>>(<Foo>[]),
        });
      }

      String renderer(Foo entry) => '${entry.id}: ${entry.title}';
    }

    class Foo {
      int id;
      String title;

      Foo(this.id, this.title);
    }
```

## The problem

My custom renderer can't be applied because of exception from template code:

`EXCEPTION: Expected a value of type '(dynamic) => String', but got one of type '(Foo) => String'`

Where from `dynamic` has appeared? I thought the value accessor will takes the `Foo` type from `options`! Without that renderer the component appears, but choosing any item throws next:

`Error: Type 'List<dynamic>' should be 'List<Foo>' to implement expected type 'List<Foo>'.`

It throws from the *material_dropdown_material_accessor.dart* file, `MultiDropdownSelectValueAccessor` class:

```
    @override
    void registerOnChange(callback) {
      selectionChangesSub = selectionModel.selectionChanges.listen((_) {
        callback(selectionModel.selectedValues?.toList());
      });
    }
```

And again — where that `dynamic` appears from? Is it real to using material dropdown with custom types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Root cause

The problem was in the fact that `MaterialDropdownSelectComponent<T>` and `MultiDropdownSelectValueAccessor<T>` **are generic directives**. `T` is `dynamic` by default.

## Solution

There is an experimental AngularDart feature — `directiveTypes`. It allows to specify generic type for any directive in the component's template. In my case missing lines are the following:

```
    @Component(
        ...
        directiveTypes: [
            Typed<MaterialDropdownSelectComponent<Foo>>(),
            Typed<MultiDropdownSelectValueAccessor<Foo>>(),
        ],
    )
    class AppComponent {
        ...
    }
```

I've stumbled on it at the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/1620). It's curious what TypeScript users do for [working around that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317577/3598091).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `MultiDropdownSelectValueAccessor` implements `ControlValueAccessor<List<dynamic>>`. Probably you have to implement your own value accessor, for example:

```
@Directive(
  selector : 'you-must-set-correct-selector-here`
)
class FooMultiDropdownSelectValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor<List<Foo>> {
  ...
}
```

The selector may introduce some attribute, for example, `[list-type=foo]`

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that. The situation is interesting: such derivative of `ControlValueAccessor<List<Foo>>` is applied to `MaterialDropdownSelectComponent<dynamic>`. It led me to the problem of specifying generic type for directives. See my solution below.