# How to pass custom type from parent to child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, angular-material

I'm trying to create an abstract table component which will use the MatTable component. The abstract table will be used as a child element and I want to pass the custom interface (which acts like type) from parent to that child.

So far I decided to pass data and table settings through one object like this:

```html
//inside the parent component

<app-abstract-table [tableProperties]="tableProperties"></app-abstract-table>
```

The `tableProperties` object is created based on the following interface:

```js
export interface TableProperties {
    columnsWithCaptions?: any[];
    dataSource?: any[];
}
```

And in `app-abstract-table` I have a field which holds data for the table:
`dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Fruit> = new MatTableDataSource<Fruit>();`
and its generic type is `Fruit`.

I'd like to pass this type somehow from parent so the whole abstract table component will be completely reusable. Is this even achievable at all? Or should I just put `any` as a generic and forget the problem?

Comment: You can create separate file, and add interface to it. Then import this file in both of your component. That's way, you don't required to pass interface as a input property.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda could you please describe more how to do this? I seems to me I did't get it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235170/how-can-i-pass-a-generic-type-parameter-to-an-angular2-component

Comment: so, the 'any' is the way to go i guess

Comment: @digitalis nope, it never is. Use `unknown` instead :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar requirement today and I did not find many resources for this, so I tried the way of C# generics and it worked. So I am posting the findings below with a small example.

So to make this work, we need to add the generic type holder to the child component like below, so that we can pass the type from the parent:

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-child',
      templateUrl: './child.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
    })
    export class ChildComponent<TType> {
      @Input() genericType?: TType;
      @Output() selected: EventEmitter<TType> = new EventEmitter<TType>();
    
      onClick(): void {
        if (this.genericType) {
          this.selected.emit(this.genericType);
        }
      }
    }
```

then from the parent, we need to pass the desired type of the object. Here I am passing the number and string for the sample.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-parent',
      templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
    })
    export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
      genericTypeNumber: number= 2022;
      genericTypeString: string= "Hello World!!";
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      onSelectedNumber(numberType: number){
        console.log(numberType);
      }
    
      onSelectedString(stringType: string){
        console.log(stringType);
      }
    
    }
```

And in the parent HTML, do the normal assignment of the property to the child component :

```
    <app-child [genericType]="genericTypeNumber" (selected)="onSelectedNumber($event)"></app-child>
    <app-child [genericType]="genericTypeString" (selected)="onSelectedString($event)"></app-child>
```

This will ensure type safety as well.
If you require a generic type inside an existing interface, then you could do something like the below.

```
    export interface IGenericModel<TCustomType> {
        id: number;
        customValue: TCustomType;
    }
```

and the child component will be like this:

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { IGenericModel } from './genericModel';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-child',
      templateUrl: './child.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
    })
    export class ChildComponent<TType> {
      @Input() genericType?: IGenericModel<TType>;
      @Output() selected: EventEmitter<IGenericModel<TType>> = new EventEmitter<IGenericModel<TType>>();
    
      onClick(): void {
        if (this.genericType) {
          this.selected.emit(this.genericType);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your table properties can be defined as:

```js
export interface TableProperties<T> {
  columnWithCaptions?: any[];
  dataSource?: T[];
}
```

Comment: ok, and now how do I take this type and replace Fruit in `MatTableDataSource<Fruit>` with it? is it... doable?

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at this: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/